# rails implementation of rake db:migrate:status

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Where is the implementation of this rake task in the rails source code?
`rake db:migrate:status`

I've searched all over the rails source code and can't seem to find the actual implementation.

Comment: i've found references to it here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/tasks/engine.rake but i want to see that actual code it's executing

Answer (score 5):

The implementation is [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f47b4236e089b07cb683ee9b7ff8b06111a0ec10/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake#L91). I found it by using the Github search bar and searching for "migrate:status".  This was about the 4th hit.